# Remote error logging in React Native

Tags: javascript, exception, logging, react-native

I want to be able to see the errors that happen in production in my React Native app.

In my Cordova app I was doing something like

```
window.onerror = function (error, msg, line) {
    Flurry.logError(...);
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar in React Native? I'm guessing I could start from [ExceptionsManager.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/cbaf58a47d12a609621405024b9b25206d80f1a6/Libraries/JavaScriptAppEngine/Initialization/ExceptionsManager.js) but I was wondering if there was something in place already.

Answer (score 2):

I found the `ErrorUtils` class that has a `setGlobalHandler` method.

```
if (__DEV__ === false) {
    var ErrorUtils = require("ErrorUtils");
    var Flurry = require("Flurry");
    ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler((error, isFatal) => {
        Flurry.logError(error, isFatal);
    });
}
```

Seems to be working fine but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be using it or if it's meant to be private.